# Parse Log In Error doesn't pop up

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I'm developing an iPhone app with Swift using Parse.
I've created a simple log in screen using Parse's PFLoginViewController. There are pop ups (UIAlertControllers) when the user does things like signing up without a username etc, but there is no pop up for when the log in credentials are invalid. Instead I just get an error in the console:

```
2015-08-23 22:50:10.246 SwifferApp[24429:1614072] [Error]: invalid login parameters (Code: 101, Version: 1.8.1)
```

I have a function for when the log in fails, but I can't present the UIAlertController over the PFLoginViewController

```
 func logInViewController(logInController: PFLogInViewController, didFailToLogInWithError: NSError?){

        var invalidCredentials = UIAlertController(title: "Invalid Credentials", message: "Incorrect username or password.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

        invalidCredentials.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Okay", style: .Default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
            //do nothing
        }))

        presentViewController(invalidCredentials, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

On the line with "presentViewController" i get the error

```
2015-08-23 22:50:10.249 SwifferApp[24429:1613783] Warning: Attempt to present <UIAlertController: 0x7c1f1a50> on <SwifferApp.TimelineTableViewController: 0x7c1b7120> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

What can I do to include a log in error pop up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out!

All I need to do was replace

```
presentViewController(invalidCredentials, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

with

```
logInViewController.presentViewController(invalidCredentials, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error describes the reason itself.

> Warning: Attempt to present <UIAlertController: 0x7c1f1a50> on
> <SwifferApp.TimelineTableViewController: 0x7c1b7120> whose view is not
> in the window hierarchy!

Your `TimelineTableViewController` is not in view hierarchy. That's why alert is not showing up. If you want to still show the alert not being in the `TimelineTableViewController` then,

Replace this:

```
presentViewController(invalidCredentials, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

With this:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(invalidCredentials, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: I still got the same error :( I know its not in the window hierarchy because the parse log in screen is currently present, but I don't know how to present the UIAlert over the parse log in screen